# python map function (+ lambda) involving conditionals (if)

Tags: python, lambda

I'm curious if it's possible to do something with the `map()`function that I can do via list comprehension.

For ex, take this list comp:

```
example_list = [x*2 for x in range(5) if x*2/6. != 1]
```

obviously, this gives me [0, 2, 4, 8].

How do I make the equivalent using the `map()` function? Doing this gives me a syntax error.

```
example_map = map(lambda x:x*2 if x*2/6. != 1, range(5))
```

Just trying to get a better understanding of how to use this function.

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to wrap the `map` around a [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) around the list:

```
example_map = map(lambda x: x*2, filter(lambda x: x*2/6. != 1, range(5)))
```

Comment: feel free to grab my answer and incorporate it here and I can delete. It was a bit too long for a comment

Comment: But the returned list length changed.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could `filter` your `map` rather than `map`ing your `filter`.

```
example_map = filter(lambda x: x/6. != 1, map(lambda x: x*2, range(5)))
```

Just remember that you're now filtering the RESULT rather than the original (i.e. `lambda x: x/6. != 1` instead of `lambda x: x*2/6. != 1` since `x` is already doubled from the map)

Heck if you really want, you could *kind of* throw it all together with a conditional expression

```
example_map = map(lambda x: x*2 if x*2/6. != 1 else None, range(5))
```

But it'll leave you with `[0, 2, 4, None, 8]`. `filter(None, example_map)` will drop the `None`s and leave you `[0, 2, 4, 8]` as expected.

Comment: I was looking for this!

Comment: This works! slight change is `example_map = map(lambda x: x*2 if x*2/6. != 1 else x, range(5))` so that element that not satisfy the condition will just be itself.

Answer (score 3):

Along side the other answers that suggests some solutions the reason of your Syntax Error is that `map` function :

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results.

So the result is in a same length as your iterable.and if you use `if` statement you need to specify an `else` too.

```
>>> map(lambda x:x*2 if x*2/6. != 1 else None, range(5))
[0, 2, 4, None, 8]
```

And as an alternative way you can use `itertools.ifilter` to filter your iterable :

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter
>>> map(lambda x:x*2,ifilter(lambda x: x*2/6. != 1,range(5)))
[0, 2, 4, 8]
```

Note that as you don't need the result of filtered list and you just want to pass it to `map` it's more efficient that use `ifilter` because it returns a generator and you can save much memory for long lists ;) (its all in python 2 and in python 3 `filter` returns generator)

Comment: "it's more efficient that use `ifilter` because it returns a generator" assuming you're using Python2 anyway. In Python3, `filter` is `ifilter` and `ifilter` doesn't exist! :) Then again in Python3, `something/6.` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah, i didn't see that OP talks about python3, any way good point i'll note that;)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it at two stages, first stage by applying filter on the list and the second stage by applying mapping function on the output list

```
list(map(lambda x:x*2, filter(lambda x: x*2/6 != 1 , [x for x in range(5)])))
```

> [0, 2, 4, 8]